# How to Fix the Drop Down Menu Which is Malfunctioning?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, opencart

My website's menu drop down seems to malfunction and it is stuck on the screen. Don't know how to fix http://www.kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/

I want to add more sub categories to this drop-down, but I wish to avoid making the drop down list too lengthy. I thus want 2 rows here in the drop-down to adjust the length list of sub-categories, but it doesn't seems to happen, instead there is a new problem - The drop-down menu item is half stuck and I am unable to fix this.

I have not made any changes and yet it seems to malfunction. No clue how to fix the dropdown menu stuck on my screen. Please advice.

```css
/* MENU */
.primary-define #menu {
 text-align: left;
 font-family: helvetica, Arial;
 /*background-color: #999;*/
}
.primary-define #menu-inner {
 position: relative;
 font-family: helvetica, Arial;
 background-color: #999; /*No color was added origninally - added to make it grey*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 
}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li {
 float: left;
 /*background-color: #999;*/
 
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li a {
 color: #666;   /*originial #666*/
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px; /*original 15px */
 padding: 0.5px 1px; /*20px 25px */ /*Padding for the dropdown elements*/
 text-decoration: none;
 /*background-color: #999;*/
 
}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li > a {
 color: #fff;
 padding: 15px 25px; /*35px*/
 font-size: 14px; /*original 18px */
 font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 100%;
 font-family: helvetica, Arial;

}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li:hover > a,
.primary-define .mainmenu > li.active > a {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); /*rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)*/
 /*font-size: 15px;*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown-container {
 top: 99%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute; /*absolute*/
 padding-left: 1px; /*added by yuvi*/
 font-size: 30px; /*added by yuvi*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown {
 margin-top: -300px; /*-999px*/
 background-color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #eee;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 font-size: 30px; /*added by yuvi*/
 padding: 10px;
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li:hover .dropdown {
 margin-top: 0;
 /*font-size: 30px; added by yuvi*/
}
}
.primary-define .mainmenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
 width: auto; /*249px*/
 list-style-type: none;
 border-right: 1px solid #eee;
 
}
.primary-define .mainmenu ul li:hover a,
.primary-define .mainmenu ul li.active a {
 background-color: #eee; /*orginiarl #eee*/
```

Comment: you mean in "Meble"? It works fine for me (FF Windows7 and Chromium Ubuntu)

Comment: It is bad in Mozilla and worse in chrome. Doesn't seem to get fixed.

Comment: I don't see any problem, tested in latest FF and Chrome - in both the dropdown seems to function normally. I think the only problem here is that you didn't describe the issue properly - probably it lays elsewhere (or your understanding of malfunction differs from others).

Comment: It was malfunctioning, but applying the solution from  qwertz1029384756 seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you for your support @shadyyx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin-top has to be -380px.

```
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown {
margin-top: -380px;
background-color: #fff;
border-left: 1px solid #eee;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]